# Having problems uploading blob directly to s3

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I have the following code:

```
var fd = new FormData();

        var key = "events/" + (new Date).getTime() + '-';

        fd.append('key', key);
        fd.append('acl', Acl);
        fd.append('Content-Type', "image/jpeg");
        fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', AWSAccessKeyId);
        fd.append('policy', Policy);
        fd.append('name', "Policy13492345");
        fd.append('success_action_status', "201");
        fd.append('signature', Signature);          
        fd.append("file",  blob);
        fd.append("filename", fileName + ".jpg");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

        xhr.open('POST', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + Bucket + '/', true); 

        xhr.send(fd);
```

When this request goes through I get the following error:

`<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Filename", ""]</Message>`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I generate my blob like so:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
                var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
                var array = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
                }
                var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
                return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: mimeString });
            }
```

This is my request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

events/1367541109750-
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

private
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

asdfasdfFASDFSDFAADSFHHVDQ
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

FsnY29udFuZ2UnLCAwLCAxMDAwMDAwMDBdLAogICAgICasdfasdfAgIFsgJ3N0YXJ0cy13aXRoJywgJyRrZXknLCAnJyBdLAogICAgICAgIFsgJ3N0YXJ0cy13aXRoJywgJyRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUnLCAnasdfJyBdLAo
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Policy134722343242345
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

basdfasdftwa/9asdfasdfx3/zasdfadsft6g=
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

C:\fakepath\495845894.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryxh8thnHAmDhZQuXE--
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured out the issue, ordering for the formdata is important, you must follow the correct order in order for the data to post correctly.

Comment: From [AWS Docs](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html#Variation_on_the_form) - the file should be the last element in the form. It took me a while to find this document. so here it is...

Comment: I'm using the blueimp jQuery File Upload  and uploading a cropped image directly to s3.  
This worked for me to append a file property to the formData inside the 'add' event.  
```
 data.formData = {
                acl: 'public-read',
                AWSAccessKeyId: res.s3Key,
                key: IMAGE_PATH,
                policy: res.s3PolicyBase64,
                signature: res.s3Signature,
                file: data.files[0]
              }```